# Custom Nodes: How to make something happen when node is added

Tags: node-editor, development

I'm creating a custom node tree and custom nodes following the blender script templates - https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/templates_py/custom_nodes.py

The template does not include an example of how to make something happen when the custom node is added to the custom tree.

What is a way to trigger something when a node is added to the tree?

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a while trying to do this with `bpy.msgbus` and then realized the solution is much easier because you just wanted to know when a node was being added to your custom tree, and not *every* tree.  Although it can be (sort of) done more generally, following is the direct answer to your question.

---

In order to be notified when a node is added, you can modify the `init` function ([line 99](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/scripts/templates_py/custom_nodes.py#L99)) in the `MyCustomNode` class.  `self.id_data` will refer to the parent NodeTree:

```
class MyCustomNode(MyCustomTreeNode, Node):
    # === Basics ===
    # Description string
    '''A custom node'''

    # ...
    # (removed for brevity)
    # ...

    # === Optional Functions ===
    # Initialization function, called when a new node is created.
    # This is the most common place to create the sockets for a node, as shown below.
    # NOTE: this is not the same as the standard __init__ function in Python, which is
    #       a purely internal Python method and unknown to the node system!
    def init(self, context):
        parent_tree = self.id_data
        print(f'{self.name} added to {parent_tree.name}')
        self.inputs.new('CustomSocketType', "Hello")
        # ...
```

<sub>(Note: the `custom_nodes.py` [template was moved](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/scripts/templates_py/custom_nodes.py) in the Blender    directory structure.)</sub>